# Charging identical spheres using induction

Tags: electricity, charge, induction

Suppose I can induce a charge Q in a conducting sphere by the traditional induction method, then why is it that the charges would be equally shared if I put this sphere in contact with another identical sphere? (resulting in a charge Q/2 in either sphere)

My understanding is that the extra electrons in the first sphere would neutralize the positive charges in the second sphere, leaving a net negative charge in the second sphere. But why do the net negative charges on either sphere at the end of it have to be equal? (Q/2)

What is the theoretical maximum for the charge that can be transferred to another identical sphere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry to bump this, but any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric field inside a static conductor will always be zero, otherwise the conducted electrons/holes/whatever would move in order to make it so. Your two touching conductive spheres make a single, symmetric conductor. The charge distribution that will result in zero electric field within a symmetric conductor must also be symmetric. Ergo, the net charge on each of the two spheres must be equal.

Comment: Thanks! Also, what would be the theoretical maximum for the charge that can be transferred to another identical sphere, assuming that the first charge had a charge Q?

Comment: If you start with charge Q, and end up with that charge equally distributed between the two spheres, how much do you think ends up on each?

Comment: Q/2, understandably.